# Dropzone js not working with another inputs

Tags: dropzone.js

I want to use Dropzone.js into a form with more than one inputs but it's not working properly.It's only working with a single form but not with more than one inputs in a single form. Is there any code which can help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read this link? >> https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Upload-all-files-with-a-button

It's a dropzone.js' tutorial explaing how to get all your form submit when you click submit  button.